# How to use the ListT monad transformer

Tags: haskell

I am a newbie to Monad Transformers in Haskell and in particular I am struggling with the ListT monad transformer.

I want to compute a list while doing some IO operations along the way.

Here is an stupid example that does not compile. I want to print `x+1` for every member x of a list.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.List
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class 
import System.IO.Unsafe

scrap :: ListT IO Int
scrap = do lift $ print "Hello"
           lift $ print 6
           x <- [6,7,8]
           lift $ print (x+1) -- code crashes here
           return 4
```

This does not compile. I get the error

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( problem.hs, interpreted )

problem.hs:41:17:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘ListT IO Integer’
                with actual type ‘[Integer]’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: x <- [6, 7, 8]
    In the expression:
      do { lift $ print "Hello";
           lift $ print 6;
           x <- [6, 7, ....];
           lift $ print (x + 1);
           .... }
    In an equation for ‘scrap’:
        scrap
          = do { lift $ print "Hello";
                 lift $ print 6;
                 x <- [6, ....];
                 .... }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I want the code to print 7,8,9. What should I do?

Comment: Just a word of warning, the docs say "The ListT monad transformer, adding backtracking to a given monad, which must be commutative.".  `IO` is not commutative (which means roughly that it doesn't matter which order you do your effects in, very much not true in `IO`).  So that means you don't get monad laws -- e.g. if you say `do { do { foo; bar }; baz }` it could behave differently than if you say `do { foo; do { bar; baz } }`.  And who knows what the difference is supposed to be? -- basically it doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: "I want to compute a list while doing IO operations along the way" -- I think you misunderstand what `ListT` does, which adds backtracking-style nondeterminism to a monad.  You sure you don't just want `IO` (which is perfectly capable of manipulating lists)?  Or maybe `WriterT [Int] IO`, which adds a list "global variable" that gets appended to ?

Comment: Your problem is that `[6,7,8]` has type `[Int]` but compiler expect `ListT IO Int`. So, you should have transformation `[Int] -> ListT IO Int`. For example, `ListT . return $ [6,7,8]`.

Comment: You should use one of the "ListT done right" libraries for the reasons luqui mentions.  [`list-transformer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-transformer-1.0.1/docs/List-Transformer.html) has some nice tutorial material. (With that library the offending line freestyle corrects would be written `select [6,7,8]`) There are several different implementations on hackage, e.g [`list-t`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-t)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a complete program to answer the question. First, I think what you need (from functionality perspective) is simpler than `ListT`, or just `IO Int`. Second, maybe you want to learn ListT, so I also provide the ListT versions. This program also serves as an example to understand `toList` and `traverse_` functions in `list-t` library. The difference is wonderfully explained in another streaming library: https://github.com/snoyberg/conduit#interleaved-effects

Before compiling, please add `mtl` and `list-t` as dependencies in the `package.yaml` file (assuming you are using stack).

```
import qualified ListT as L
import Control.Monad.Trans (lift)

main :: IO ()
main =  putStrLn "#### Just IO version: maybe you are actually looking for this."
     >> scrapJustIO >>= print
     >> putStrLn "#### ListT version serializing everything into a list before output."
     >> L.toList scrapListT >>= print
     >> putStrLn "#### ListT version as stream (what list-t is actually for)"
     >> L.traverse_ print scrapListT

scrapJustIO :: IO Int
scrapJustIO = do
    putStrLn "Hello"
    print 6
    mapM_ (print . (+1)) [6,7,8]
    return 4

scrapListT :: L.ListT IO Int
scrapListT = do
    lift $ putStrLn "Hello"
    lift $ print 6
    x <- L.fromFoldable [6,7,8]
    lift $ print (x+1)
    return 4
```